# How to start native app development for Android

Tags: android, installation

I have tried installing sdk for android but didn't get success. I am installing it on windows, after several tries I am still unsuccessful in using the android sdk. Can anybody guide me a bit to overcome the issues I am facing?
I am web developer trying to start native app development.
I had same issue with phone gap too.

Answer (score 0):

If your facing problem setting up your development environment then follow this tutorial..
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9lb8mLvFB0

See to it that all the dependencies are installed properly..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I did the same way but still some issues. I am going to try the process again.

Comment: Its important that you perform the steps in given order or else u wld have to manually set the sdk path in eclipse so do follow the tutorial given properly

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)